# Why my BEFORE UPDATE trigger takes values from the NEW record?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm updating data with QGis on a Postgres table. The operation consists of splitting a polygon in two parts, which means that QGis updates the original polygon (to become one of the 2 new ones) and creates a second one. On save the result is stored in the table `table1` as 2 records, one with the original `id` (the PK) and the other with a new `id`. But I need to keep the original polygon (for history) and I try to do this with a trigger function that simply *should* make a copy of the original record from `table1` to another table `table2`, totally similar to the first one, except that I removed the SERIAL and the PK.

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER area_reduc_1
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ((pg_trigger_depth() < 1))
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_area_before_upd();
```

My trigger function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field_survey.save_area_before_upd()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

IF (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'table1') AND (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 

    INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM table1 d
    WHERE NEW."id" = d."id" AND NEW.area_ref = d.area_ref
    ;
END IF;  

RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
```

BUT in `table2` I end up with attribute values that are the ones I recorded in QGis, i.e. the ones coming from `NEW`! Why and how can I solve this?

I use QGis 2.8.2 (but that should not matter) and PostgreSQL 9.3.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit.

Comment: are you looking for OLD.id ...?

Comment: God !! yes !  It seems so obvious now.  I'm out of my office, I will try tomorrow.  But still, why didn't my solution work ?  Thank you very much, @Aneesh Mon N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use record type OLD to access the old values as you do NEW to access the new values when updating a record in a table.

Refer: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html